# Case Sensitive drive, can't install illustrator

Tags: macos, filesystems, adobe-illustrator

I have a case sensitive drive on my macbook. I went to install Illustrator but I got the error that it can't be installed on a case sensitive partition (in 2013!!!). I went and partitioned my paltry 128 GB drive and made the new partition case insensitive.  After that I tried to install Illustrator and again, same error. It didn't even bother to look to see if there was a new drive. Are there any command line switches or anything I can use to force it to install on the new partition?

Comment: What are the actual filesystems you are using?

Comment: I know it's not a direct solution, but unless you really need the case sensitivity, it may be worth taking the hit now and redoing your core partition as vanilla HFS. Adobe products aren't the only ones that'll choke.

Comment: Complain to Adobe. You're paying them enough that they ought to be able to produce a functional product.

Answer (score 3):

See https://bitbucket.org/lokkju/adobe_case_sensitive_volumes.

From the description: "adobe_case_sensitive_volumes is a function call hijacking library that forces volumes to look like they are case insensitive."

It's pretty hacky, involves creating a sparse bundle and some symbolic links to trick the installer into thinking that it's writing to a case-insensitive volume. But it does look like it was designed to solve just what you're trying to do.

See also [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120118103118881) on a more drastic solution (directly hacking the installer).

Comment: I don't suggest using third-party fixes like this.  Never mind if it works right now, Adobe may release updates which break it in obvious or subtle ways.  Plus you have to trust the developer of the third-party fix.  I agree with @tanantish above, if you don't have a reason to be in case-sensitive partition, then backup all of your files and make a clean install.